# How to print the bean values in Eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, printing, console, javabeans

I am having two bean classes bean1 and bean2.In my logic I have set some value in the bean.Example Bean1 has id and  indicator then address.In that indicator is boolean value .
In my clien logic , based on piece of code i make it boolean value as TRUE .Now I want to test the bean whether the changes are reflected or not.
When I give

```
System.out.println(bean1);
System.out.println(bean2);
```

It doesnot shows the bean value
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

In your class you have to implement method

```
public String toString() {
    return ...;
}
```

The value returned by that method will be printed by `System.out.println()`

Comment: I want to print the values inside the bean class.

Comment: Please clarify the question then, I don't understand the expected behavior.